# Center a div both horizontal and vertical having a width in %

Tags: html, css

I have a login page and I want to center it both horizontally and vertically.
I have written this code but it's not working.

**HTML:**

```
 <div class='loginMainDiv'>
  <div class="loginTable">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.loginMainDiv {
    height:550px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

.loginTable {
   display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: `loginMainDiv` is 100% wide, so can't really be centred (or it is not needed). You haven't given `loginTable` any width, so how wide do you want it to be? Also, provide a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of what you can do:

http://jsfiddle.net/jUN83/

Play around with the margin of `.loginTable` until it fits your requirements.

**Used CSS:**

```
.loginMainDiv {
    height: 550px;
    text-align:center;
    background: #FFDDDD; /* For clarity */
}
.loginTable {
    width: 75%;
    margin: 50% auto;
    background: #DDDDFF; /* For clarity */
}
```

Both `background: #...` statements can be deleted without any consequences.

Answer (score 1):

use the code like this

html

```
<body>
    <div id="loginMainDiv">
          <div id="loginTable">Content goes here</div>
    </div>

</body>
```

css

```
body, html, #loginMainDiv {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}


#loginTable{  
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: blue;    
        position:absolute;
        left:0; right:0;
        top:0; bottom:0;
        margin:auto;    
        max-width:100%;
        max-height:100%;
        overflow:auto;
}
```

[demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/jBMBR/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
.loginTable {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. `7 percent` from top. Right and left is auto that will make the div center align. You can set your width accordingly.

```
.loginMainDiv {
    height:550px;
    width: 40%;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 7% auto 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: It's in his question to center align it both horizontal AND vertical.

Comment: Center align of page depends on the height and width of div.

Answer (score 0):

Give the parent `display: table;` and the element which has to be centered `display: table-cell;` Vertical center via `vertical-align: middle`;

Example: http://jsbin.com/epaxob/1/edit

```
.loginMainDiv {
    height: 550px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.loginTable {
    display: block;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var windowWidth = $(window).width(); //retrieve current window width
  var windowHeight = $(window).height(); //retrieve current window height

  $('.loginTable').css('top',(windowHeight/2)+'px');
  $('.loginTable').css('left',(windowWidth /2)+'px');

});
```

this code will always fix your div in the center of any screen..
if you face any problem please let me know